# Move data from array of not aligned structs to array of aligned in c++

Tags: c++, memory, optimization

What is the best way to move data from array of CameraSpacePoint to array of PointXYZ?

```
struct CameraSpacePoint
{
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
};

 __declspec(align(16))
 struct PointXYZ
 {
      float x;
      float y;
      float z;
 };

 constexpr int BIG_VAL = 1920 * 1080;

 CameraSpacePoint  camera_space_points[BIG_VAL];
 PointXYZ          points_xyz[BIG_VAL];
```

My solution:

```
CameraSpacePoint* camera_space_points_ptr = &camera_space_points[0];
PointXYZ*         points_xyz_ptr          = &points_xyz[0];

for (int i = 0; i < BIG_VAL; ++i)
{
    memcpy(points_xyz_ptr++, camera_space_points_ptr++, sizeof(CameraSpacePoint));
}
```

Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Just use `std::copy`...

Comment: @You: `std::copy` would require conversion from `CameraSpacePoint` to `PointXYZ` not currently provided...

Comment: @You it's causes types mismatch

Comment: If these points are aligned for SIMD purposes, this is still a somewhat unfortunate layout

Comment: @harold: I am creating an adapter between two APIs (Kinect SDK 2.0 and PCL) and clamped in such conditions

Comment: Right, don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: Is it OK to give the `camera_space_points` some padding (like `camera_space_points[BIG_VAL + 1]`), and use SSE for the copy?

Comment: @harold: I can't.

Comment: The padding or the SSE? Without padding there are still tricks, but the last item becomes annoying

Comment: @harold: I can't do anything with that structures one is from Kinect SDK 2.0 and anouther one is from PCL.

Comment: @DmitryZhivaev why not create a union with both types? I updated my answer to reflect this additional information. According to [class.union#1] using the union for this case should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @rmm19433 : I can't do anything with that structures one is from Kinect SDK 2.0 and another one is from PCL.

Comment: @DmitryZhivaev the idea was to reuse the memory. To further elaborate could you add the function signature you are working with?

Comment: @rmm19433 :Unfortunately, in my context it is impossible to use such a union.

Comment: I have the feeling that your approach is already the fastest possible. The inner loop should consist of no more than three memory loads and stores, so six instructions touching 28 bytes of memory. I'd be surprised if this didn't saturate the memory bus of the CPU.

Comment: @cmaster: Maybe i can optimise for loop, to reduce variable i check? I've heard about templates, that can expand such a simple for into sequence of executions at the cost of compiling time and source files size.

Comment: @DmitryZhivaev: harold's answer is the best currently performance-wise. But as cmaster says, it may not matter, as you're like already memory bound. How much time does it take currently to do that loop?

Comment: @geza: I run it sequently in loop 100 times and get equal results with memcpy 12 and 16 bytes, about 390ms for each.

Comment: Your loop control is standard counted loop; your compiler knows how to optimize that. You won't be able to do anything for it because the loop control won't take any time at all in your case. And I literally mean "won't take any time": Your CPU will be executing the loop control instructions in parallel to the memory loads and stores which take much longer. So the loop control's latency is hidden behind the memory accesses.

Comment: That's ~6GiB/sec read, and ~8GiB/sec write speed. What machine do you have?

Comment: @geza: [sysinfo img](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18EwqDiigKR-Uga7epCgJ3nOXgNgjm1RH)

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can improve on these numbers with prefetching, and using `MOVNT` instructions for writing data. This way you can utilize the cache best. I'm sure that that machine can do better, I expect a 1.5x-2x speedup with proper cache usage.

Answer (score 3):

As always, readability and maintainability trumps other concerns. Write what you mean, and don't fix what isn't a problem: measure before you optimize.

```
std::transform(camera_space_points, std::end(camera_space_points), points_xyz,
    [](auto c){
        return PointXYZ{c.X, c.Y, c.Z};
    });
```

This is what you should always write as default. By their [assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/M2E1OW) and a [quick benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/e-OWndHguf9SSb08JL0Q6ddMAsI), this is pretty much equivalent to the `memcpy` version.

On a more hand-wavy note, optimizers are really good at micro-optimizing simple code such as copying a large chunk of memory, manual optimizations are rarely better.

Comment: Doesn't look so great to me, two loads and two stores per struct while it could be done with one each

Comment: Thats awesome! Your solution is 66% faster than mine! 20 ms vs 12 ms! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Passer By: I hurried. If i make one time copy then the result is above (20 ms vs 12 ms). If i make 10 times copy sequently it will be 57ms vs 115ms. And if i make 100 times copy sequently it will be 400ms vs 1140ms. And in my case memcpy is faster and better suited.

Comment: I think it is highly subjective, which version is more readable. For me, OP's version is more readable than the solution you've presented (I'm not saying that your version is bad/not readable, just OP's version is more readable **for me**). So I disagree that "This is what you should always write as default". Plus, OP seeks for the "most efficient" way. In this case, readability/maintainability is not the most important thing. Sure, if it can be readable/maintainable, then we should go for it, but if readability/maintainability hurts performance, then we shouldn't use such a solution.

Comment: @geza Readability might be subjective, but in this particular case I argue it is _objectively_ more readable and maintainable. Imperative vs declarative aside, this version frees you from thinking about trivially copyable types, off-by-one errors and misaligned reads, all of which are excruciatingly error prone. On the topic of performance, since we don't have the exact situation where this is being used, I can hardly argue much in either way.

Comment: This answer is not in the spirit of the question. Also, the std::transform is a poor choice to use in a maintainable c++ code because it is an unsafe API.

Comment: @0kcats Unsafe... how? Bounds checking is *your* responsibility, and no this isn't analogous to `sprintf`.

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry, it is only unsafe for those who may forget to check the  bounds. Could you add the check?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is making sure you copy chunks of 16 bytes. That way the copy can be optimized better in terms of instructions that copy 16 bytes at once (without any surrounding shuffles or other unnecessary complications), if they exist (they exist on x64 so on eg Xbox One and PC this can help). The `PointXYZ`s will be 16 bytes, so writing 16 bytes to them is fine. The source has elements of 12 bytes, so every time one of them is copied this way there is also 4 bytes from the next element in it, they end up in the padding of the target `PointXYZ` and will be ignored. The *last* `CameraSpacePoint` does not necessarily have 4 readable bytes after it, it might end just before an unmapped/unreadable memory region, so there we need to be careful to not read further - unless that array can be extended a little to guarantee that the memory exists.

For example:

```
auto dst = ::dst;
auto src = ::src;
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < BIG_VAL; ++i)
    std::memcpy(dst++, src++, 16);
// last point is special, since the src may not have 16 bytes left to read
std::memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(CameraSpacePoint));
```

(on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3bk5wz))

Comment: Doesn't unrolling the loop help a little bit? I see that clang unrolled it, but MSVC didn't, an OP likely uses MSVC.

Comment: @geza it should help since MSVC is being a bit silly there

Comment: Btw, does the exact implementation matter in this case? Input data is ~24MB, the whole process is likely memory bandwidth bound, isn't it?